# CSS beginner : use background image over gradient without the transparency of the image

Tags: css

thanks for reading

I am trying to use a background image OVER a gradient, but with every solution I found, my background image ends up being transparent so the colors are not the same on the background image.
I tried to inverse the "url" and the "webkit-linear-gradient" but this doesn't work.

Here is what I am trying to get :
[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnTbE.png)

And here is what I get with my code:
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUqdU.png)

Here is the background image I use if this helps : [background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdxpt.png)

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Battle Royale de la Culture Générale</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>



html {
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #DA07EA, #FB7018), url("background-bubbles.png");
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
background-blend-mode: saturation;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you so much !